# Not able to login to ArgoCD CLI available after subpath

Tags: argocd

I have deployed my ArgoCD in EKS cluster. UI is available under address https://example.com/argocd and it seems to be a problematic for the CLI to login to argocd.

```
argocd login example.com    
Username: admin
Password: 
FATA[0013] rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = unexpected HTTP status code received from server: 503 (Service Unavailable); transport: received unexpected content-type "text/plain; charset=utf-8"



argocd login example.com/argocd
FATA[0000] dial tcp: lookup example.com/argocd: no such host
```

My ingress configurations says

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "argocd_ingress" {

  metadata {
    name      = "argocd-ingress"
    namespace = "argocd"
    annotations = {
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol" = "HTTPS"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.argogrpc" = "[{\"field\":\"http-header\",\"httpHeaderConfig\":{\"httpHeaderName\": \"Content-Type\", \"values\":[\"application/grpc\"]}}]"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports"        = "[{\"HTTP\": 80}, {\"HTTPS\": 443}]"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect" = "443"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect" = "{\"Type\": \"redirect\", \"RedirectConfig\": { \"Protocol\": \"HTTPS\", \"Port\": \"443\", \"StatusCode\": \"HTTP_301\"}}"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme"              = "internet-facing"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type"         = "ip"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.rule-argocd" = "{\"type\":\"redirect\",\"redirectConfig\":{\"host\":\"#{host}\",\"path\":\"/argocd/\",\"port\":\"443\",\"protocol\":\"HTTPS\",\"statusCode\":\"HTTP_302\"}}"       

    }
  }

  spec {
    ingress_class_name = "aws-application-load-balancer-controller"
    rule {
      host = join("", var.domain_name)
      http {
        path {
          backend {
            service {
              name = "argogrpc"
              port {
                number = 443
                #number = 80
              }
            }
          }
          path      = "/"
          path_type = "Prefix"
        }

        path {
          backend {
            service {
              name = "argocd-server"
              port {
                number = 443
                #number = 80
              }
            }
          }
          path      = "/argocd"
          path_type = "Prefix"
        }            
        path {
          backend {
            service {
              name = "rule-argocd"
              port {
                name = "use-annotation"
              }
            }
          }
          path      = "/"
          path_type = "Prefix"
        }                  
      }
    }
    tls {
      hosts = var.domain_name
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way for me to do the argocd cli?

Comment: Consider opening a feature request on their GitHub but that's probably not supported indeed. Most people would have argocd.example.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the argocd CLI there is the possibility to specify a subpath for the `login` command with the parameter `--grpc-web-root-path`. This can be used to login if argocd is not running under the root path.

**Example**:
Web UI of argocd runs under `mycluster.com/argocd`
Login via argocd CLI: `argocd login mycluster.com --grpc-web-root-path argocd`

More information at: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/commands/argocd_login/#options-inherited-from-parent-commands